# Setting environment variables with Redis Queue

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, rq

I am new at RQ and I am trying to implement it within my flask app. The main goal of one of my routes is to update values from a database. To setup my worker I am using the following:

```
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection
import redis
import os

@app.before_first_request
def start_worker():
    def runworker():
        redis_url = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL") or 'redis://'
        conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)
        with Connection(conn):
            worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
            worker.work()
    tp = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    tp.submit(runworker)


def get_redis_connection():
    redis_connection = getattr(g, '_redis_connection', None)
    if redis_connection is None:
        redis_url = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL') or 'redis://'
        redis_connection = redis.from_url(redis_url)
    return redis_connection


@app.before_request
def push_rq_connection():
    push_connection(get_redis_connection())


@app.teardown_request
def pop_rq_connection(exception=None):
    pop_connection()
```

then the update route queues the update job

```
@app.route('/update')
def update_db():
    q = Queue(connection=conn)
    job = q.q.enqueue('app.tasks.update_task', parameters)
    job_id = job.get_id()
    return {"job_id": job_id}, 201, {"Content-Type": 'application/json'}
```

finally, the worker runs the updating funcion

```
def update_task(parameters):
    # script to update DB
```

I know the worker setup (almost) works because if I switch the update_task function to something simple like:

```
def update_task(seconds):
    for i in range(seconds):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    return "Hello world"
```

it works. However, for the real function I keep running into the problem that my environment variables are not being defined because when I run the actual update, I get exceptions saying my variables are None or something similar.

Does anyone know how to handle environment variables within RQ? Should I declare them again somewhere like a config file?

Comment: An answer would depend on which OS you're running this on. Would you be able to add that information to the question?

Comment: It's either Ubuntu 19 or 20

Comment: Ah, ok. You can set the environment variable in Bash like this: `export REDIS_URL=redis://...` where the `...` would be replaced by your Redis URL.

Comment: Yes, but I don't thinks that's the issue. The variables are being defined because flask can use them alright. The RQ woker is the one that's not getting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it's better to use `multiprocessing`

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def runworker():
    redis_url = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL") or "redis://"
    conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)
    listen = ['default']
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
        worker.work()

pp_worker = Process(target=runworker)
pp_worker.start()


@app.teardow_appcontext
def teardown_rq(self):
    pp_worker.terminate()
```

aaand that does the trick. Just if anyone was wondering about it.